# Android support-v4 is missing a method

Tags: android, compatibility, android-support-library

I am seeking to use ViewPager 's `getCurrentItem()` method

I've encountered this issue before but I am not sure how to fix it. The issue was that one version of android-support-v4 revision did not have this method, and that a more updated revision had it.

On this machine though, I pulled Android Support straight through the Android SDK Manager, and this version of the android-support-v4 (rev. 7) does not have `getCurrentItem()` method. My project now will not compile on this machine

How can I get previous revisions of android-support-v4.jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Android SDK Manager, I have the latest Android Support package, and the `android-support-v4.jar` contains `getCurrentItem()` on its `ViewPager` implementation, as I am using it.

The JAR I have is 271,754 bytes, dated 2012-03-21 19:02, with an `md5sum` of `c6c2148762c614d3bad120ca01491e34`.

Comment: `The method getCurrentItem() is undefined for the type ViewPager` everything else works, `awesomePager.getCurrentItem()`

Comment: @CQM: What is the date, size, etc. of your JAR?

Comment: @CQM: Are you compiling this `AwesomePager` from source? Or getting it from a JAR? If the latter, then perhaps that JAR is the thing that is out of date.

Comment: I was getting it from the JAR, how do I add the v4 source to my project another way? I suppose I could add it as a package in my src, but perhaps there is a lib? or maybe I just find the ViewPager object and add that .java document

Comment: @CQM: `AwesomePager` is not part of the Android Support package. I assumed from your variable name that you are using http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/trunk/AwesomePager/

Comment: ah I believe it is related to my woes, but I was able to add the v4 source to my project and everything is fine

Comment: I still have difficulty, how would I add "getCurrentItem" to the awesomepager kind of adapter?

Comment: @CQM: `getCurrentItem()` is a method on `ViewPager`, not `PagerAdapter`. You do not need to add it to `ViewPager`, as it is already there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it should be there in the API, but... if that won't work, I think that your underlying question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117523/how-can-i-get-page-number-in-view-pager-for-android).

EDIT:  Well, it looks like one of the later commentators suggested "you can just use getCurrentItem()!" so I'm not sure that actually answers the underlying question at all.  :(

To answer the actual question you asked, you can find support-v4 lib r6 [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/android/support-v4/r6/support-v4-r6.jar)