# how to know which fragment is visible in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 5 fragments in my application in a `viewpager` i want to know which `fragment` is visible  when i am horizontal swapping in `ViewPager` i have tried with

@Override

```
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
```

but it is always giving 0 the starting `Fragment` position.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117523/how-can-i-get-page-number-in-view-pager-for-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know which fragment is current use `yourViewPager.getCurrentItem()`

Comment: it will always gives you 0 that is the first fragment even you are in 2 or 3.