# Android+Robotium: is view of ViewPager visible to user

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I'm using a `ViewPager` to display 2 Fragments as tabs. Once the according activity is loaded, both fragments are loaded immediatly, while only the first one is visible to the user.

Therefore `view.isShown()` is not sufficent for testing, as this method returns true for the second fragment which is not visible to the user.

`ViewAsserts.assertOnScreen(decorView, view)` seems to behave the same way and is therefore useless for solving this problem.

I'm aware that some similar questions have been asked, but none of their answers is satisfying my needs. So how to test this behavior (using Robotium)?

**Solution:**

I solved it according to Leon's suggestion by using a flag within the fragment like this:

```
private static boolean isVisibleToUser = false;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    MyFragment.isVisibleToUser = isVisibleToUser;
}

public static boolean isVisibleToUser() {
    return isVisibleToUser;
}
```

implementing it as a *static* method I can use it in my test this way:

```
assertTrue(MyFragment.isVisibleToUser());
```

the only drawback to this solution is that I have to implement these 2 methods in every single Fragment I want to test this way... any improvements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `setUserVisibleHint` inside your fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) { 
         //Fragment is selected in ViewPager
         //Put your "on appear" validation/loading here
    }
}
```

This method will fire every time you show or hide the fragment in the `ViewPager`.

As opposed to `view.isShown()` this method does take a "loaded but not visible" state into account.

Comment: sounds good, but how could i actually **test** it within a test class? (using robotium/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2)

Comment: I'm not familliar with Robotium, so I can't help you there. However the method will fire every time a fragment is added to/becomes visibile or leaves/is removed from a view. You can  then check the isVisibileToUser boolean to see if it was added (true) or removed (false).

Answer (score 1):

use `OnPageChangedListener` to detect changes and maintain a reference to the currently visible fragment/page.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Alternatively `GetCurrentItem()` may work for you as detailed here: [How do you get the current page number of a ViewPager for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117523/how-can-i-get-page-number-in-view-pager-for-android)

Comment: is there a way to check if there is a specific layout visible to the user? (getVisibility is not a solution in this case as it would always return VISIBLE)