# mViewPager.getCurrentItem() doesn't return correct position for first & last pager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am trying to get the page number of the view pager, I came across many Stackoverflow Q & A, they all stated to use

```
currentposition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

But this method is not working for the first & the last pager.

How can this problem be solved ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does this mean it not gave correct position can you please explain more ?

Comment: have you know about ViewPager index start with "0" ?

Comment: it returns 1 for both 0 & 1 position, also it returns second last position for both second last & last.

Comment: It is ViewPager built-in method so it never gave wrong index so something going wrong on your code.

Comment: No, there exists a problem, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16749660/2715065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
This Method use:-


mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {


             int  currentposition = pos;

                // Log.e("Current Postion", "" + pos);




            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks !  `onPageSelected(int pos){ currentposition = pos; }` solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a pagelistener for your viewpager? If not then you can do following -

```
PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);


private static class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
        public void onPageSelected(int pos) {               
               currentposition = pos;
    }
}
```