# Get the position of the ViewPager on first and last visible fragment

Tags: android

I implemented in my app a `ViewPager` to slide between fragments. After a long research I discovered that if I want to get the position of the visible fragment I should use:

```
mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

But for some reason, when I'm on the first or the last fragment, the position doesn't change. It remains 1 on the first fragment, instead of 0, respectively size - 2 for the last, instead of size - 1. (In case of the first fragment, the theory is applicable only when I start the `ViewPager` from a different position from the first)

How can I get the first and the last position of the ViewPager. I even tried to send the position from the `ViewPagerAdapter`, but here I am dealing with the same thing, as the last changing of the position is happening before the first or the last fragment.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650223/mviewpager-getcurrentitem-doesnt-return-correct-position-for-first-last-pag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YourPagerActivity.class add listener in create method

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            String positions=position + "";

            Toast.makeText(YourPagerActivity.this, positions, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried this example, but it works only if the ViewPager starts at position 0. If I start the ViewPager at any other position, it doesn't workd properly

Comment: It works from all startpositions. Where and how do you set the startposition of pager ?

Comment: ,I set the start position in the Activity, like this mViewPager.setCurrentItem(Start);

Comment: I don't see your code. i set startposition right after setadapter in oncreate method and  toast shows right startposition.

Comment: @euosecom that's exactly where I set it as well. But where should i put the setOnPageChangeListener ? in the Activity that host the Viewpager (where I set the adapter and the start position), in the FragmentsPagerAdapter or in the Fragment is use for the ViePager ? I currently use it in the Fragment, but still no results for the first and last Fragments.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I use the setOnPageChangeListener inside the fragment and do the necessary actions inside the onPageSelected method. As this method only gets triggered always but for the first position clicked, in the onActivityCreated method I check whether the fragment is the first one clicked or not and do the necessary actions for this fragment. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put listener to fragment.
Put setOnPageChangeListener into oncreate method in YourPagerActivity.class

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reklamapager);


         new yourAdapterAsync().execute();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        String positions=position + "";

        Toast.makeText(YourPagerActivity.this, positions, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});

  }
```

and in onpostexecute of yourAdapterAsync set startposition

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog 
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    ImageAdapterFromRes adapter = new ImageAdapterFromRes(YourPagerActivity.this, textArray, urlArray, bitmapArray );
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(startposition);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I would have done it in the activity but I need the position value in fragment. Since the position must change from fragment to fragment, from there I can only transfer the first position clicked, as in my Fragment I receive the bundles from the FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Ok but getCurrentItem and setCurrentItem works right only in PagerActivity. In PagerAdapter you get  actual position in public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position)...Hardly help without your code...

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated now. Need to use `ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` instead.

for example,

```
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

**[REFRENCE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))**

Answer (score 0):

```
oncreate     
 leftNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                Log.e("pos","pos "+position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    leftNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rightNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else if (position == 5) { //inplace of 5 u can use your dynmic value
                    leftNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rightNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else if (position > 0 || position <5){
                    leftNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rightNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.e("poss","poss "+position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                Log.e("possss","posssss "+state);
            }
        });
```